# Create ffdshow audio processor instance error

Tags: c#, video, directshow, directshow.net, ffdshow

I downloaded latest ffdshow ([ffdshow_rev4527_20131203_clsid](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ffdshow-tryout/files/SVN%20builds%20by%20clsid/generic%20builds/)) and installed it. I want to use **ffdshow Audio Processor** filter in my application. Whenever I want to create an instance of it, fails with cast error. Neither GraphStudio nor GraphEditPlus can add filter but surprisingly GraphEdit can add & use it!

Do you have any idea? I set "no limitations" for number of instances.

Thanks

Comment: How do you instantiate and what is the error exactly. Typical issue is confusion between `Win32` and `x64` code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my fault. I unchecked "Use for these applications" part. I thought I'd unchecked it but I was wrong.